# Can R language find a generic solution of the first order differential equation?

Tags: r, differential-equations

Can R language find a generic solution of the first order differential equation?

For example:

```
(5x-6)^2 y' = 5(5x-6) y - 2
```

PS:
That can be easily solved by hand, i.e. particular solution is:

```
y = 1/(5(5x-6))
```

and generic

```
C*(5x-6)
```

I need to understand whether R can do  it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can use the R library `deSolve` to obtain numerical solutions of ODEs. See `?deSolve` for details.

Here is a worked-through example based on your ODE.

1. Load the R library

   ```
   library(deSolve);
   ```
2. Define the differential equation

   ```
   # Define the function
   f <- function(x, y, params) list((5 * (5 * x - 6) * y - 2) / (5 * x - 6)^2)
   ```
3. Set `x` values for which to solve and initial condition

   ```
   # x values for which to solve
   x <- seq(2, 10, length.out = 100);

   # Initial value y(x=2) = 1/20
   y0 <- 1/20
   ```
4. Solve the ODE

   ```
   # Solve ODE
   df <- as.data.frame(ode(y0, x, f, parms = NULL));
   ```
5. Plot theoretical (algebraic) solution and numerical solution from `deSolve`

   ```
   # Plot
   library(ggplot2);
   ggplot(df, aes(time, `1`)) +
       stat_function(
           fun = function(x) 1/(5 * (5 * x - 6)),
           aes(colour = "Theoretical"),
           size = 4) +
       geom_line(aes(colour = "deSolve"), size = 2) +
       labs(x = "x", y = "y")
   ```

[image]

Comment: Thank You very much for your kind answer. But let me understand - the proposed answer is NUMERICAL solution, is not it ? My question is about solving "symbolically", I mean I want to get generic form of solution: y = 1/(5(5x-6)) + C* (5x-6)

Comment: @AlexanderChervov It's important to understand that (base) R is not a CAS (like Mathematica or Maple). I am not aware of any symbolic ODE solver for R, but perhaps somebody will correct me. So symbolic solutions are not (easily) obtained. There do exist some R packages like `Ryacas` that offer symbolic math functionality to some extent. I have no experience with them, and quite frankly I think you're better off using Mathematica (or the likes). R's plentiful strengths lie elsewhere.

Comment: Thank you again for your answer, let me accept it. But let me ask question about symbolic solution separately: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50231104/is-there-symbolic-ode-solver-in-r