# Is there symbolic ODE solver in R ? (ODE = ordinary differential equation)

Tags: r, differential-equations

**Question:** Is there symbolic ODE solver in R ?  (ODE = [ordinary differential equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_differential_equation))

I am afraid there is NO... but let me confirm from experts ...

For example, solve:

```
> (5x-6)^2 y' = 5(5x-6) y - 2
```

Here: y - unknown function, y' - its derivative

(It is easy to solve by hands: y =  1/(5(5x-6)) + C* (5x-6) , but I want to get that answer from R).

---

**What I know:**

**1) There are NUMERICAL (not symbolic) solvers:**

I know there are numerical ODE  solvers like library(deSolve),
see answer here: 
[Can R language find a generic solution of the first order differential equation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50229410/can-r-language-find-a-generic-solution-of-the-first-order-differential-equation/50230098?noredirect=1#comment87478037_50230098)

**2) There are symbolic packages :**  (but they do not seem to contain ODE solvers)

There are symbolic packages in R like 
see  Ryacas and  rSymPy and also some basic symbolic calculation in base R, see:
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/4775/symbolic-computation-in-r/4778

**3) Brief overview of various differential equations solvers for R**: 
https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/DifferentialEquations.html

However I was unable to find  sumbolic ODE solvers (((

Comment: I'm not sure if partial derivative but try: `?D` .... deriv is a generic function with a default and a formula method. It returns a call for computing the expr and its (partial) derivatives, simultaneously. It uses so-called algorithmic derivatives. If function.arg is a function, its arguments can have default values, see the fx example below.

Comment: @TonyHellmuth thank you for your comment, however I do not quite understand it... would you be so kind to give any details ? In case my question was not clear let me phrase again: I need to get solution of ordinary differential equation...

Comment: Your best bet might be to find a good C++ library and then use `rcpp` to hook it to R

Comment: Perhaps the `deriv` function in R is only good for complete functions not partial ones, sorry!

Comment: I'm not aware of a symbolic ODE solver for R. One workaround might be to call something like [Wolfram Alpha from R](https://gist.github.com/sebkopf/a8bf2033f3eda527fa61).

Comment: you list `rSymPy`  and since `SymPy` [seems to include ODE solvers](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/solvers/ode.html) does that count ... ?

Comment: @BenBolker Great ! That might be a solution. I might just overlooked it.

Comment: But check that it solves the system `x'=z, y'=y, z'=x` correctly. SymPy 1.0.3 does not.

Comment: @LutzL does rSymPy supports ALL functions of SymPy ? The documentation https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rSymPy/rSymPy.pdf seems very short and mentions only very few functions

Comment: That depends on if it is a translation to R or a wrapper around the Python code. If the latter, I would expect that all functions are accessible.

Comment: @LutzL thank you ! By the way, do not you know is there any on-line site to check rSymPy ? There is one for SymPy itself: http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/solvers/ode.html , but I some online R resource which we checked does not help. PS at the moment we have problem installing rSymPy package ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**I've had a play around with `Ryacas`, and you can in fact get symbolic solutions to some simple ODEs without too much work. Unfortunately, YACAS fails to find a solution for your example ODE. However, depending on the ODEs you are exploring, this might still be of use. If not, I'm happy to remove this post.**

As an initial simple example, let's consider the following ODE: `y'' + y = 0`:

1. Load the library

   ```
       library(Ryacas);
   ```
2. Since `Ryacas` is just an interface to YACAS, we can use YACAS' `OdeSolve` to solve the ODE

   ```
   yacas("OdeSolve( y\'\' + y == 0 )")
   #expression(C70 * exp(x * complex_cartesian(0, -1)) + C74 * exp(x *
   #    complex_cartesian(0, 1)))
   ```

   This gives the correct solution `const * exp(- ix) + const * exp(+ ix)`.
3. Unfortunately when using your particular example, `OdeSolve` fails to find a solution:

   ```
   yacas("OdeSolve( y\'\' == (5 * (5 * x - 6) * y - 2) / (5 * x - 6)^2 )")
   #expression(y(2) - (5 * ((5 * x - 6) * y(0)) - 2)/(5 * x - 6)^2)
   ```

   The same happens when we use the [YACAS online demo](http://www.yacas.org/yacas_online/yacas_online.html).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer !

Comment: useful! do you know whether it is possible to test an ODE provided a set of coordinates for x0 and y0? Perhaps OP's example can be solved providing that?